# ssh-copy-id testnode fails with ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname testnode: Temporarily failure in name resolution

Tags: ssh, error-handling, hostname, hosts

I am not able to mention the SSH Generated Key to my test node.

This is the output I get whenever I run the command `ssh-copy-id`:

[image: Output Image, when I run the command 'ssh-copy-id']

```
aibak@aibak-Inspiron-3542:/$ ssh-copy-id testnode
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname testnode: Temporarily failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Can you reach your testnode? Try ping and see the results. The problems seems more related to name resolution than to SSH. It should work if you use IPs instead of names (make sure you reach those IPs)

Comment: aibak@aibak-Inspiron-3542:~$ ansible linuxnode -m ping
linuxnode | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname linuxnode: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}

This the result of ping.

Comment: Try using IP address instead.